# What do you call Oracle's way of ora-XXXX exception reporting?

Tags: oracle, exception

Oracle throws ora-xxxx for sql malform exception and ora-xxxx for xxxx exception, I am trying to put this into a report, what is this called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are often referred to as `Named System Exceptions`, as in exceptions that you don't have to define yourself and are already present in the system.

Oracle's manual only talks about [`Predefined exceptions`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/07_errs.htm#i9355) though.